# how to export / import role in ITIM 5.1?

Tags: tivoli-identity-manager

I am new to Tivoli Identity Manager, while learning Role Administration i came across concept of Exporting roles.

I want to know whats the need to export / import roles in ITIM and how do we do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Export / import features are so that you can move a configuration from one system to another.  This is primarily used when testing a system out on a development system, and then you want to move those configuration settings (e.g. roles) to a production system.  It is also useful for creating a backup of the system in case something is accidentally removed or changed (although it should definitely not be the primary method of backup for the ITIM/ISIM system).

Answer (score 0):

The ISIM roles are stored in the ISIM LDAP instance you've configured.
You can export and import the roles in this node. All the roles are stored here.
ou=roles, erglobalid=00000000000000000000, ou=something, DC=somethingLikeCOM

The last node will be your base DN.

Export all the roles under this subtree mentioned above and then import them when required.
We normally do this for backups or for deploying a configuration to an other environment.